# How to re-trigger CosmosDBTrigger events in Azure Cosmos DB or get triggered event if there is an exception while processing the event

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have configured a CosmosDBTrigger using Azure functions in Cosmo DB but once the event is triggered it will be lost as per my basic understanding but is there any way to store the trigger event till the event is processed by my business logic.
I have read about Lease collection but much details regarding lease collection is not given in context with Trigger.

Can  someone help me with storing Triggers as we do in MQ.

Comment: You mean you want to *retry* a failed function. You also mentioned *how*. You use a queue. MQ isn't a code execution service, it's a queue that pushes messages to some other service for execution. If that service doesn't *consume* the message, it's retried

Comment: Post your messages to an Azure Queue and delete them if the Azure Function succeeds. If it doesn't, the message will reappear in the queue by itself after its lease time expires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lease collection is used to store the checkpoints regarding the position in the Change Feed where the Trigger is at currently and to help distribute load across multiple instances of a Trigger.

If you Azure Function that has the Trigger does not wait for the business layer to finish processing, you can use an EventHub, Service Bus or Storage Queue to maintain a batch identifier and track status.

The Trigger sends a `IReadOnlyList<Document>` to the Function, which is basically a list of documents. You can serialize that to a Queue Message adding an identifier that is related to your Business Logic process and then have another Trigger (tied to the Queue or EventHub or Service Bus) that picks up the message, checks the status of the batch against the Business Logic and retries if needed or updates the status if done.

I think the major point would be to avoid bottlenecks, if the volume of changes picked up by the Trigger (which comes from your collection activity) is fast but your Business Logic speed is low, the intermediate queue might grow at a faster rate than you can handle, but it depends on the cadence of your data and scenario.

Comment: I can still see an underlying concern. Even if the CosmosDBTrigger were to post messages to a queue, what happens if there is an error posting to the queue. How does the trigger deal with exceptions and failures? Is there any approach that can guarantee a document's (message) is delivered exactly once to a queue?

Comment: No Event-based triggers have retry mechanism at this point. This is by design and to avoid an infinite bill due to a non-transient exception. Once Azure Functions add retry policies to triggers, then opt-in retry will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Think about having your Azure function write a message to a Service Bus with the relevant payload. Then have a second function to read the service bus and process the payload and give you all your familiar queuing constructs like message completion / abandoning and deal letter queues.